# SSL not valid for domain

Tags: https

I am in the process of setting up a webmail server and one of the requirements is to have a signed SSL which I obtained through StartCom. During the setup it asked me to define a sub-domain name (which I did). After the review was complete I received the key and created a new file to hold it.

I configured apache2 correctly and all that is working, but I am getting the following error on connection.

> The certificate is only valid for the following names: host.siriusdesigner.com, siriusdesigner.com

now the server hostname is host.siriusdesigner.com and the FQDN is siriusdesigner.com (registered).

Am I missing something here? Or do I need to have some sort of wildcard in place (which means I would need to call them about upgrading my account to class 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a wildcard won't work unless you have purchased an expensive SSL certification which supports that.

Accessing `https://domain.com` I can see that the SSL looks like its working as intended, however accessing `https://www.domain.com` it reports about `host.` Unless I've mistaken and you do want to use `www.` then you need to add the SSL cert to the `www.domain.com` not `domain.com`, often people make mistakes of not thinking www is a sub domain when it is.